# Are {/bin, /lib, /sbin} symlinks into /usr in Ubuntu?

Tags: filesystem

I do not have access to an Ubuntu system or chroot. I was hoping if someone could tell me if the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/Quantal/UsrMerge) is accurate in saying:

> For Quantal, merged /usr should be supported. On new systems installer should create {/bin, /lib, /sbin} symlinks into /usr.

Comment: See:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/difference-between-bin-and-usr-bin

Comment: The wiki page was a proposal for discussion, not a final roadmap. Regardless of whether it was implemented in Quantal (13.04), it is not implemented in 17.10 and is not planned for 18.04.

Comment: @Terrance not exactly true anymore.  As of Fedora 17 (=2012) they do exactly this.

Comment: @user535733 I apparently got fooled by the shiny Ubuntu wiki. Compared to the [Arch](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2012-March/022625.html) discussion, the Ubuntu page convinced me that the merge happened.

Comment: @Rinzwind You know, that is interesting.  By reading through the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) pages it would make me think that Fedora wouldn't be FHS compliant then.

Comment: @Terrance I think a motivator is that most distributions will not even boot into single user mode without mounting `/usr` from the initramfs.

Comment: FHS is a guideline though. We are LSB compliant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base). LSB is based on POSIX, and SUS  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification

Comment: Regardless of symlinks or not, if the link itself does not cross over hard drives this configuration would work fine once in recovery mode if it was a link or not.  By default, fstab is not loaded when going into recovery mode so a symlink crossing hard drive lines would then fail and the files would not be loaded.

Comment: @StrongBad Oh, I forgot to mention feel free to call me Sterrance.  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

```
$ ls -l /
total 2097260
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           4096 okt 28 11:46 bin

drwxr-xr-x  21 root     root           4096 okt 21 10:32 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           4096 okt 18 20:32 lib64

drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root          12288 okt 28 11:46 sbin
```

You are looking at a proposal. Besides that: we follow Debian and unless they do not set this up we probably will not.

===

The link from Terrance is a little bit invalid: Fedora did this from release 17 (= 2012). See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove on this. But Debian, Ubuntu never went for this setup.

Comment: [Here](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) is the relevant Debian wiki page. It was actually [enabled by default in Stretch testing](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=839046) but backed out due to a bug. There's a good chance it will be enabled by default in Buster.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. As of at least Ubuntu 20.04, new installs use symlinks (existing systems won't be modified).

```
$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
$ ll / | grep -E "usr|bin|lib"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Apr 23 15:02 bin -> usr/bin/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Apr 23 15:02 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Apr 23 15:02 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Apr 23 15:05 usr/
```

Seems like an unannounced change: [Why are /bin and /sbin now symlinks in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242157/why-are-bin-and-sbin-now-symlinks-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: How is it possible they didn't mark it anywhere? I've upgraded from 19.10 and looks like it didn't change that (or maybe it failed to apply this change?)

Comment: Good point. Updating comment as this only applies to new installs.