# Why are /bin and /sbin now symlinks in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

tl;dr: In Ubuntu 20.04, folders such as /bin and /sbin are now symlinks to the same folders in /usr.  Why was this change made and shouldn't the release notes mention it?

This took a few days, but I tracked down some issues I was having in system setup.  As part of a preseed post-install set of commands, I unpack a .tar.gz onto new systems, which puts some files in various folders, including `/bin`. I've been doing this since Ubuntu 14.04.  With Ubuntu 20.04, my systems weren't bootable after install (various failure to mount errors).

I finally narrowed the issue down to this unpacking step, and realized that I'm replacing the /bin folder and making many things inaccessible.  What a lovely surprise. The fix is easy enough; dump files in /usr/bin, instead.

Specifically, the following symlinks are new in 20.04, apparently (below via multiple fresh installs):

```
$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
$ ls -l / | grep -E "usr|bin|lib"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Apr 23 15:02 bin -> usr/bin/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Apr 23 15:02 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Apr 23 15:02 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Apr 23 15:05 usr/
```

Compare with 19.10 (edit: this system was upgraded from 18.04 I think; whoops):

```
$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 19.10
$ ls -l / | grep -E "usr|bin|lib"
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 11 07:41 bin
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root  4096 Nov  4  2019 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov  3  2019 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Apr  6 13:29 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Aug  5  2019 usr
```

Arch does this, apparently [starting years ago](https://www.archlinux.org/news/binaries-move-to-usrbin-requiring-update-intervention/), and the overall topic is the [Filesystem Hierachy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
.
It's not in the release notes: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of 2014's https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121235/merging-usr-bin-and-usr-sbin-into-bin-gnu-linux. Interestingly, my 20.04 systems (upgraded from 19.10 and earlier) are NOT linked, so the change for new installs might be several releases old.

Comment: Thanks for the additional link! I would not consider this a duplicate, as there's two unanswered questions here: Why did Ubuntu just now make this change, and why did they not include it in release notes.

Comment: Probably this is the case in fresh installs of LTS version. I have the links in 18.04, in 20.04 but not in an install off 19.04. Just an observation... I only do fresh installs, never release-upgraded.

Comment: @Gertlex Probably we cannot answer those two questions as we're only a community of (mostly) average Ubuntu users, *not* paid employers of Canonical Ltd. (the Ubuntu company). You would probably have better luck asking Canonical directly.

Comment: Right. The hope is that someone who has tracked down e.g. relevant mailing list discussion will use that as an answer.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/

Comment: All this is great until someone run `dpkg -x file.deb /`. Then the system will be ruined  almost completely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hadn't noticed this change, so I dug into it a little bit.  I'm guessing it was not in the release notes because it was really an upstream change in Debian:

- [UsrMerge at Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge)

[This Ubuntu announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2018-November/001253.html) is the only official notification of the change I've seen

> Merged-usr is now the default in Disco for new installations only

Some other general info

- https://lwn.net/Articles/670071/ (Preparing for a merged /usr in Debian)
- https://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Debian-usr-Merge
- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/483921/ (Various notes on /usr unification)

Comment: Good sleuthing! It sounds like this possibly took effect with 19.04, and based on other comments, mayyybe got included in a later point release of 18.04, so could affect fresh installs of that, too.

Comment: Thanks for finding this!! I’ll test older Ubuntu from before. With docker you can try this easily. On Ubuntu 18.04 it certainly didn’t have this feature.

Comment: Since 19.04 this feature is enabled on Ubuntu, I've re-checked answer with this command `docker run -it ubuntu:19.04 ls -la`