# Where does /usr/bin/grep come from in Ubuntu Focal

Tags: dpkg, grep

When I run `which grep` on Ubuntu Focal, I get `/usr/bin/grep`. However, `apt-file search /usr/bin/grep` does not show a package which delivers it. Moreover, `dpkg-query -L grep` only shows `/bin/grep` (among other related executables). So, what package delivers `/usr/bin/grep`?

Comment: On my Ubuntu system, `/usr/bin/grep` and `/bin/grep` are the exact same file.  Probably it gets copied over during the installation process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `grep.deb` installs the `grep` binary in `/bin`. In recent times, the `/bin` and `/usr/bin` have [been unified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980871/are-bin-lib-sbin-symlinks-into-usr-in-ubuntu) in Ubuntu and many other linux distributions by symlinking `/bin` to `/usr/bin`. Thus, any binaries installed in either directories end up in `/usr/bin`.

`/usr/bin` is the directory that is included in the search PATH. Therefore, `which grep` identifies the file as `/usr/bin/grep`.