# Is it possible to prevent usrmerge package installation on systems upgraded from 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, apt, 20.04, upgrade, 21.04

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS system. I plan to upgrade it to 20.04.2 LTS and then to 21.04 for testing purposes.

I see that using system with `usrmerge` package installed will not be comfortable for me. Because of issues like [failed `dpkg -S $(which grep)`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1358655/66509) and [failed `ldd`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1313596/66509).

How can I prevent installation of `usrmerge` package during upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern Ubuntu 21.04 system `ubuntu-minimal` [recommends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/ubuntu-minimal) the installation of `usrmerge`. We need to prevent this behavior.

So the order of actions will be the following:

1. Boot existing Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS system and install upgrades to it.
2. Create special pin/lock file dedicated to `usrmerge` package by

   ```
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-usrmerge
   Package: usrmerge
   Pin: version *
   Pin-Priority: -1337
   EOF
   ```
3. Upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04.2 LTS.
4. Upgrade Ubuntu to 21.04 (and then to 21.10 if needed).
5. Enjoy the normal system without unnecessary symlinks.

Note: pin/lock file should be created before step 4.