# usrmerge of {/bin, /sbin, /lib}: How is the system supposed to be?

Tags: filesystem, symbolic-link, 21.10

It seems that

1. some systems have a symlinks like this

   ```
    /bin -> usr/bin
    /lib -> usr/lib
    /sbin -> usr/sbin
   ```
2. Some systems have single file-symlinks of executables in these directories like this:

   ```
   /bin/some_exe -> usr/bin/some_exe
   ```

   (this is what `usrmerge` seems to accomplish as well)
3. And some systems have some symlinks and some executables (including duplicates).

### Questions

1. Which state is the one that's meant to be?
2. How do I get into the state that's meant to be from the other states?

Comment: @user535733 except Ubuntu is typically more opinionated than Debian, so it seems fair to ask what "should be" the configuration. Debian has decided that [Debian 12 and beyond will all be merged-/usr](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/tech-ctte/-/blob/master/994388_merged_usr_advice/draft.md) and Ubuntu will presumably be the same in a future release. DarkTrick had some problems that looked like they were caused by a `usrmerge` failure; I don't know what the 'default state' should look like, to suggest a course of action.

Comment: Not quite sure why folks would be using `usrmerge` for anything other than testing and filing bugs on Debian (not Ubuntu) packages...usually done in a container or VM and wiped instead of repaired. Perhaps that could be clarified in the question.

Comment: "Some systems have single file-symlinks of executables" ... can you give an example of a usrmerge system that's supposed to be like this? I don't remember seeing any distro discussing a layout like that for usrmerge

Comment: @muru that was an approach openSUSE took back in 2012. I understand it did not go well. Here's a historical wiki page describing the effort: https://en.opensuse.org/index.php?title=openSUSE:Usr_merge&oldid=53591

Comment: This `usrmerge` modern glossy method creates serious problems for debugging with `dpkg -S` and `ldd`. So on my systems I prevent its installation by installing 18.04 LTS and then upgrading it. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1358790/66509 for details.

Comment: @muru This is the state that usrmerge would create (and did create on my system) from your comment I also infer, that the link should be /bin -> /usr/bin (?)

Comment: @DarkTrick I don't have a VM on hand to test, but installing it on an 18.04 Docker container, the message I get is "the /{bin,sbin,lib}/ directories are symlinked to their counterparts in /usr/" which would match (1), not (2).

Answer (score 0):

The eventual state is/will be 1. The three dirs symlinked to their /usr counterpart. Maybe sbin will be lumped in with bin as well. The only systems I have encountered where the executables are individually linked are BusyBox systems.