# why there is two identical bash?

Tags: bash, checksums

I have seen some  bash scripts start with `/user/bin/bash` and others`/bin/bash`

I did a check-sum with `cksum`

```bsh
2695035772 1392424 /usr/bin/bash
2695035772 1392424 /bin/bash
```

they look exactly the same, so what's the difference.Is it more appropriate to use one than one another in bash scripts?

Comment: These days, /bin and /usr/bin are the same directory (one a link), so bash is just the one file.

Comment: Related: [Why are /bin and /sbin now symlinks in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242157/why-are-bin-and-sbin-now-symlinks-in-ubuntu-20-04) and [usrmerge of {/bin, /sbin, /lib}: How is the system supposed to be?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379811/usrmerge-of-bin-sbin-lib-how-is-the-system-supposed-to-be)

Answer (score 7):

`/bin` is linked to `/usr/bin` so the two are literally the same. Same goes for `sbin`. It is due to historical, compatibility reasons. `bash` predates Linux so to be more compatible we still use both.

```
$ ls -l  / | grep bin 
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              7 apr  3 00:13 bin -> usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              8 apr  3 00:13 sbin -> usr/sbin
```

We are going towards `/usr/bin/bash`. Fedora is ahead of Debian/Ubuntu and OpenSUSE on this (those use `/bin/bash`).

Comment: Debian uses /bin symlink to /usr/bin too, for new installs (I think since buster). For upgraded installs, you must temporarily install usrmerge package, which does the conversion in post install hook. See https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge

Answer (score 4):

As [ubfan1 said in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408545/why-there-is-two-identical-bash#comment2447121_1408545), the `/bin` directory is now (not sure *when* this happened, but it's unimportant) simply a link to `/usr/bin`, so `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` point to the exact same place in the system, thus the identical checksums.

Answer (score 3):

There is only a single "bash" executable. The directory `/bin` is now replaced by a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`. Therefore, both `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/bash` are the same executable.

Historically, `bash` as a core utility used to be in `/bin`. Hard drives were small, so there was a need to keep the system partition small. Core binaries were collected in `/bin`, which resided on the hard drive from which the system booted. A directory `/usr/bin` was then designed to host other binaries, that eventually were present on a partition on another drive, mounted later in the boot process.

Storage is nowadays plenty, so there is a tendency to do away with the historical split between `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. Many distributions started to move any executable to `/usr/bin` instead, but, for compatibility reasons, still have a `/bin`, which really is only a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`. This way, the traditional shebang `#!/bin/bash` continues to work, although `/bin` my disappear completely in the future.