# awk works in different ways on desktop and server

Tags: awk

Just a simple question.

Why this bash command works properly on Ubuntu Server and finds out the ISBN code
and doesn't work on my Ubuntu Desktop? Both systems are 22.04 LTS.

```
echo "ISBN 5-02-013850-9" | awk '/ISBN [0-9]{1}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}-[Xx0-9]{1}/ {print $0}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Likely one of them is using `gawk` (GNU awk) while the other is `mawk`, which doesn't appear to support the RE brace quantifiers. Check with `awk -W version`.

`mawk` appears to be the default `awk` in Ubuntu 22.04, but if you subsequently install `gawk` it will take preference via the `update-alternatives` mechanism.

See [Built-in regex's do not support brace-expressions](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/25).

As an aside, `[Xx|0-9]` should probably be `[Xx0-9]` (unless you're trying to match a literal `|`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Yes, you are right - the desktop version uses mawk indeed. 
P.S. Thanks. I have made a mistake by copying the wrong line from the history. Thanks.

Comment: Also helpful might be `dpkg -S $(which awk)` -- which package does `awk` come from? On my systems, it isn't from a package.

Comment: @dannyman note that since Ubuntu systems implemented the "usrmerge", things like `dpkg -S $(which awk)` may no longer work as expected (depending on the order of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`). See for example [Where does /usr/bin/grep come from in Ubuntu Focal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358655/where-does-usr-bin-grep-come-from-in-ubuntu-focal)