# awk or sed command to replace line break plus text containing spaces

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, search, awk

[An answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20416/80644) to another question suggests `sed -i 's/original/replacement/g' file.txt` to replace specific words in a text file. My starting situation looks like this:

```
        Item: PRF
        Type: File
        Item: AOX
        Type: Folder
        Item: DD4
        Type: File
```

My ending situation should look like this:

```
        Item: PRF^Type: File
        Item: AOX^Type: Folder
        Item: DD4^Type: File
```

Notes: (1) The Ask Ubuntu interface seems to suppress some of the leading spaces before Item: and Type:. There are in fact eight leading spaces. (2) I may have erred in using simplistic examples of Item. The items are actually partial Windows paths (lacking e.g., D:), some of which are quite long. A more accurate example would be Item: Folder\Some Folder\A file name.txt.

I've tried this, with and without double quotes:

```
sed -i 's/\n"        Type: "/\^"Type: "/g' file.txt
```

That gives me no errors, but also no changes. Also tried this:

```
awk '/ "        Item: " / { printf "%s", $0"^" } / "        Type: " / { gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0); print $0 }' source.txt
```

I tried that to verify that I would be changing only those entries with eight blank spaces before "Item." That didn't work. Trying it with no spaces and no double quotes, as in the answer (below), also failed. Trying it with `gawk -i inplace` produced source.txt containing zero bytes.

My title initially specified `sed`. An answer proposing `awk` alerted me to that alternative, which (now that I'm looking at it) seems more capable. But I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: "but also no changes" .. do you mean changes *in* the file? If you want in-place changes a la `sed -i`, you'd need to use GNU awk with the `-i inplace` option

Comment: Ah. I thought one answer (below) was saying that GNU awk was the default in Ubuntu. Apparently I misunderstood that: https://askubuntu.com/a/1420570/80644. With `sudo apt install gawk` the `-i inplace` option did modify source.txt, though with undesirable results (see edited question, above).

Comment: I don't remember if it's the default or not, but anyway, the command in the answer works for me, but your post has some weirdness: `/ "        Item: " /`, `/ "        Type: " /` - these don't match anything in the input file you have shown, so nothing gets printed, so your input file is replaced with nothing.

Comment: *"The items are actually partial Windows paths"* ... Was your input file edited on Windows at some point? ... If yes, then it might have `\r\n` carriage return(*Windows style newlines*) and you need to run it through e.g [`dos2unix file`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183893) to correct that before processing it with either `sed` or `awk`

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code for how to code format properly (either indent by 4 spaces or wrap with triple-backticks)

Comment: The Windows-style newline was the solution. To fix that, I opened the file in `gedit` and used Save As to change the line ending from Windows to Unix\Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`awk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/awk.1plan9.html) … It is a straightforward one-liner like so:

```bash
awk '/Item:/ { printf "%s", $0"^" } /Type:/ { gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0); print $0 }' file
```

That is … If the line has `Item:` in it, then print it without appending a newline(*`printf` doesn't append a newline by default*) but append the `^` character at the end … and if the line has `Type:` in it, then remove all leading space and print it appending a newline(*`print` appends a newline by default*).

The above command will not modify the original file but, will rather output modified text in the terminal.

**To edit the original file** in-place, use the `-i inplace` option of **GNU `awk`**(*Might be the default on Ubuntu ... Check with `awk -W version`*) or if not, you can install [`gawk`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/gawk.1.html) then use it like so:

```bash
gawk -i inplace '/Item:/ { printf "%s", $0"^" } /Type:/ { gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0); print $0 }' file
```

Comment: This is a wilderness to me. (1) Would I be better advised to use printf "%s", $0 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46455937/711879)? (2) If printf $0 doesn't append a newline in the first part, why does it append a newline in the second part? (3) I think [ \t] refers to any occurrence of space or tab, but what do / and + characters do in gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0)?

Comment: (1) yes `printf "%s", $0"^"` would be a better safety measure … (2) It’s `print`(*not `printf`*) in the second part … (3) `//` enable regular expressions and `+` matches multiple occurrences of the regular expressions inside `[]`

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. Clarification on print vs. printf: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Output_with_print_and_printf. Follow-up question regarding + : doesn't gsub (as distinct from sub) already match multiple occurrences within the specified string - or is that defeated by ^ ? Anyway, I wasn't successful so far. Editing the question to update.

Comment: @RayWoodcock "doesn't gsub (as distinct from sub) already match multiple occurrences within the specified string?" ... It does if you **don't** anchor the regex to the the beginning of the line with `^`(*there will always possibly be **only one** space or tab that satisfies this condition ... hence the `+`*) ... It's worth mentioning that in your case `sub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$0)` is an alternative option too ... Also, please notice that we only see your provided example input and expected output and write our answers to help you achieve just that ... We don't see the other context you see :-)

Answer (score 1):

By default, sed only loads one line at a time into its pattern space. You can use the `N` command to load another line.

In fact, your question is a variant of a well-known "one-liner" for joining lines based on the initial character(s) of the following line<sup>1</sup>:

> **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "=".**
>
> ```
> sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n=/ /;ta' -e 'P;D'
> ```

So given

```
$ cat file.txt
    Item: PRF
    Type: File
    Item: AOX
    Type: Folder
    Item: DD4
    Type: File
```

(which has 4 initial spaces), then

```
$ sed -E -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n {4}Type: (File|Folder)/^Type: \1/; ta' -e 'P;D' file.txt
    Item: PRF^Type: File
    Item: AOX^Type: Folder
    Item: DD4^Type: File
```

Add `-i` or `-i.bak` to edit the file in place once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

---

Alternatively, you could use the following non-streaming `ed` editor script to match the `Type:` lines, substitute `^` for the leading spaces, then **j**oin to the preceding line, writing the result back to the same file:

```
g/^ \{4\}Type:/s//^Type:/\
-1,.j
wq
```

You can implement that as a non-interactive shell one-liner:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^ \{4\}Type:/s//^Type:/\' '-1,.j' 'wq' | ed -s file.txt
```

See [The GNU ed line editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) for details.

---

1. see for example [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one)

Comment: In the `sed` command, what does :a do?

Comment: @RayWoodcock `:a` sets a label for the conditional branch `ta`. See [Commands for sed gurus](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands)